# Как создать background из треугольников?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-variables

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как показано на изображении выше, на фоне есть треугольники схожих, но разных оттенков цвета.

Мне удалось получить такой же цвет, который на изображении `#4C27B3`

https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzXowL

<sub>Примечание:
Ссылка умерла</sub>

Как добиться этого эффекта с помощью CSS?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to create background with triangle shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56211792/7394871) от участника  [@JoyFulCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11520625/joyfulcode).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56211792/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете рассмотреть несколько фонов для достижения этой цели, но это кажется случайным фоном, поэтому вам придется использовать много слоев.

Вот пример на случай, если вы хотите иметь повторяющийся узор.

Я буду использовать другой цвет, чтобы вы могли легко понять форму:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient( 45deg, red    calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0),
    linear-gradient( 45deg, black  calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0)  50px -50px,
    linear-gradient(-45deg, blue   calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, orange calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0) -50px -50px,
    linear-gradient(-225deg,green  calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0),
    linear-gradient(-225deg,pink   calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0)  50px  50px,
    linear-gradient(225deg, yellow calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0),
    linear-gradient(225deg ,purple calc(0.7072 * 50px),transparent 0) -50px  50px;
    
  background-size:100px 100px;
}
```

Затем вы можете оптимизировать его, используя переменные CSS:

```css
body {
  --d:100px; /* Dimension */
  --g:calc(0.7072 * var(--d)/2),transparent 0; /* 0.707 = cosinus(45deg)*/
  background:
    linear-gradient( 45deg, red    var(--g)),
    linear-gradient( 45deg, black  var(--g))  calc(1 * var(--d)/2) calc(-1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, blue   var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, orange var(--g))  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2) calc(-1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(-225deg,green  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(-225deg,pink   var(--g))  calc(1 * var(--d)/2)  calc(1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(225deg, yellow var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(225deg ,purple var(--g))  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2)  calc(1 * var(--d)/2);
    
  background-size:var(--d) var(--d);
  
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Наконец, вы можете использовать окраску hsl(), чтобы создать узор из того же цвета, что и у вас:

```css
body {
  --d:100px; /* Dimension */
  --g:calc(0.7072 * var(--d)/2),transparent 0; /* 0.7072 = cosinus(45deg)*/
  --c:256, 64%; /* Base color */
  background:
    linear-gradient( 45deg, hsl(var(--c),20%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient( 45deg, hsl(var(--c),25%)  var(--g))  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2)  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, hsl(var(--c),27%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, hsl(var(--c),32%)  var(--g))  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2)  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(-225deg,hsl(var(--c),30%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(-225deg,hsl(var(--c),22%)  var(--g))  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2)  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(225deg, hsl(var(--c),40%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(225deg ,hsl(var(--c),42%)  var(--g))  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2)  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2);
    
  background-size:var(--d) var(--d);
  
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Теперь у вас легко может быть любой фон:

```css
.box {
  --d:100px; /* Dimension */
   --c:256, 64%; /* Base color */
   
   
  --g:calc(0.7072 * var(--d)/2),transparent 0; /* 0.7072 = cosinus(45deg)*/
  background:
    linear-gradient( 45deg, hsl(var(--c),20%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient( 45deg, hsl(var(--c),25%)  var(--g))  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2)  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, hsl(var(--c),27%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, hsl(var(--c),32%)  var(--g))  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2)  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(-225deg,hsl(var(--c),30%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(-225deg,hsl(var(--c),22%)  var(--g))  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2)  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2),
    linear-gradient(225deg, hsl(var(--c),40%)  var(--g)),
    linear-gradient(225deg ,hsl(var(--c),42%)  var(--g))  calc(-1 * var(--d)/2)  calc( 1 * var(--d)/2);
    
  background-size:var(--d) var(--d);
  
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--d:50px;--c:120,20%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--d:70px;--c:20,80%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--d:20px;--c:10,20%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--d:30px;--c:220,20%"></div>
```

В ближайшем будущем вы сможете сделать то же самое с меньшим количеством кода, используя конический градиент.

```css
.box {
  --d:100px; /* Dimension */
   --c:256, 64%; /* Base color */
   
  background:
    conic-gradient(hsl(var(--c),20%) 0.125turn,
                   hsl(var(--c),32%) 0.125turn 0.25turn,
                   hsl(var(--c),27%) 0.25turn  0.375turn,
                   hsl(var(--c),42%) 0.375turn 0.5turn ,
                   hsl(var(--c),30%) 0.5turn   0.625turn,
                   hsl(var(--c),22%) 0.625turn 0.75turn ,
                   hsl(var(--c),40%) 0.75turn  0.875turn,
                   hsl(var(--c),25%) 0.875turn 1turn)
    0 0/var(--d) var(--d);
  
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--d:50px;--c:120,20%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--d:70px;--c:20,80%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--d:20px;--c:10,20%"></div>
<div class="box" style="--d:30px;--c:220,20%"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56212104/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>